# Why is it safe to send form data (incl. passwords) via a POST request to my node server?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, http-post, password-protection

We are doing lots of stuff to keep things secure when dealing with authentication, and I am still a beginner and trying to understand. What I don't understand at all, however, is why it is safe to just send form data to my node.js server (which, for example, then handles authentication).

When a user types in an email/password combination on my frontend, and i send it to the backend, wouldn't it be possible to intercept and read out this data?

Comment: It's ok, because https (tls) provides encryption, integrity protection (message authentication) and a lot more. It's obviously insecure without https.

Comment: thank you! but why then so often do I (for example) need to put a (in my case node.js-)server between my client application (say, a single page js application) and authentication providers like auth0 or stripe etc.? why cant i send these things from client to e.g. auth0 straightaway?

Comment: The short version is, you actually can, but that's a different oauth/openid connect flow. A comment is way too short, the keywords you are looking for are (federated) identity, openid connect and implicit flow.